# Display a figure with different labels on the left and right side using the image() function in matlab

Tags: matlab

Assume there is an array of values which will be displayed with the image() function in matlab:

```
figure1 = figure('Name', 'Somename', 'Colormap', map);
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,...
    'XTick',[0.5 : (length(string_array1) - 0.5)],...
    'XTickLabel', string_array1,...
    'XGrid','on',...    
    'YTick',[0.5 : (length(string_array2) - 0.5)],...
    'YTickLabel', string_array2,...
    'YAxisLocation', 'left',...
    'YGrid','on',...
    'YDir','reverse',...
    'Layer','top');
xlim(axes1,[0.5 (length(string_array1) + 0.5)]); % preserve the X-limits
ylim(axes1,[0.5 (length(string_array2) + 0.5)]); % preserve the Y-limits
box(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1, 'all');
image(values, 'Parent', axes1);
```

This returns a figure with labels on the left y-axis and the bottom x-axis. I would like to provide additional information, included in string_array3 which is of the same length as string_array2 and is to be displayed on the right side of the figure. How do I do this? I realise there are threads on similar topics with the plot() function but I can't transfer the offered solutions to my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new transparent axes placed over `axes1` and adjust its limits/properties so that they fit with it. Then you can add your own labels.

For example, add these lines at the end of your code:

```
%// Dummy labels
string_array3 = {'X_right';'Y_right';'Z_right'};

%// Create new axes
axes2 = axes('Position',get(axes1,'Position'),'Color','none','YAxisLocation','right','YDir','reverse','XTick',[],'YTick',[]);

%// Adjust limits and properties...
set(axes2,'YLim',get(axes1,'YLim'),'YTick',0.5 : (length(string_array3) + 0.5),'YTickLabel',string_array3);
```

and that should work.

Whole code with dummy data:

```
clc
clear

values = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];

string_array1 = {'a';'b'; 'c'; 'd'};
string_array2 = {'X';'Y';'Z'};

figure1 = figure('Name', 'Somename');

axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,...
    'XTick',[0.5 : (length(string_array1) + 0.5)],...
    'XTickLabel', string_array1,...
    'XGrid','on',...    
    'YTick',[0.5 : (length(string_array2) + 0.5)],...
    'YTickLabel', string_array2,...
    'YAxisLocation', 'left',...
    'YGrid','on',...
    'YDir','reverse',...
    'Layer','top');

hold(axes1, 'all');

xlim(axes1,[0.5 (length(string_array1) + 0.5)]); % preserve the X-limits
ylim(axes1,[0.5 (length(string_array2) + 0.5)]); % preserve the Y-limits

box(axes1,'on');

image(values,'CDataMapping','scaled', 'Parent', axes1);

%// Dummy labels
string_array3 = {'X_right';'Y_right';'Z_right'};

%// Create new axes
axes2 = axes('Position',get(axes1,'Position'),'Color','none','YAxisLocation','right','YDir','reverse','XTick',[],'YTick',[]);

%// Adjust limits and properties...
set(axes2,'YLim',get(axes1,'YLim'),'YTick',0.5 : (length(string_array3) + 0.5),'YTickLabel',string_array3);
```

And output:

[image]